# foreign chars in file name on Android

Tags: android, sd-card, createfile

```
File outputFile = new File(path, clickedKey+".txt");
OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
fos.write(data.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

This piece of code works when a path doesn't contain chars like: "ąóźżę" (special characters from polish language).
If the path contains any of them `fos.write` works but there's no effect (new file isn't created with "foreign" path name, but the path exists).
My question is: what can I do to fix it?

File managers apps like "Astro", "File Manager" etc. work without any trouble with such characters.

I try also this:

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();
CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();

ByteBuffer bbuf = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(clickedKey+".txt"));
CharBuffer cbuf = decoder.decode(bbuf);
String s = cbuf.toString();

bbuf = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(path));
cbuf = decoder.decode(bbuf);
String path_s = cbuf.toString();

File outputFile = new File(path_s, s);
OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
fos.write(tab.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

but it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When my phone was connected by ADB and I was checking new files with DDMS, there wasn't any file on "foreign" path. But in fact, files were in phone!

I checked it, with file manager direct in my phone :)
It strange. But I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the encoding? in eclipse: Edit > set Encoding > utf-8 or 16